# Format output of string via printf

Tags: c, printf

i'm just trying to **format output of console application** and one command does not work.

```
printf("%2s|%10s|%10s|%13s|%15s|%15s|%13s|%25s|%4s\n", 
    "No.", "Jmeno", "Prijmeni", "Datum narozeni", "Narozen v", "Bydliste",
    "Telefon", "E-mail", "Vek");
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: `"Datum narozeni"` is 14.  A bit wider than `%13s`.

Comment: You should post the exact output you got and explain how it differs to your expectation

Comment: @dbush It appears i have corrupted definition of printf, trying to fix it

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I had **corrupted definition of printf**, solved it with reinstall of visual studio.